# How could i pass a value from a child component to parent, when i have multiple child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I creat multiple  components, they have the same hierarchy, and inside they i also call other component call , now i want to create functions on my  which will update the values i'm passing as props to my  component. I manage to pass the functions as props, but can't manage to pass the value from child as parameters to the functions, so i could update only the props especific to that child.

App

```
function App() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [content, setContent] = useState(images)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(content.votes)

  console.log(count)

  const upVote = (id) => {
    alert('up =>', id)
  }

  const downVote = () => {
    alert('down')
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="grid">
        {content.map((picture, index) => {
          return <Card key={index} picture={picture} teste={[upVote, downVote]}/>
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Card

```
function Card({ picture, teste }) {

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="container">
        <img
          width="300"
          alt={`id: ${picture.id}`}
          src={picture.src}
          className="image"
        />
        <Options votes={0} originalPost={picture.original_post} teste={teste[0]}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Options

```
function Options({ votes, originalPost, teste }) {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(votes)
  const [styling, setStyling] = useState('#696969')

  function countStyle(count) {
    if (count > 0){
      setStyling('#008000')
    } else if (count < 0) {
      setStyling('#B22222')
    } else {
      setStyling('#696969')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => teste(count)} className="buttons">teste</button>        
      <button title="Down vote" onClick={() => { 
        setCount(count - 1)
        countStyle(count-1)
        // style(count - 1)
      }} className="buttons">-</button>

      <span title="Vote counter" style={{color: styling}} className="counter">{count}</span>

      <button title="Up vote" onClick={() => {
        setCount(count + 1)
        // style(count + 1)
        countStyle(count +1)
      }} className="buttons">+</button><br></br>

      <a href={originalPost} 
        target="_blank"
        title="Click to check the original post"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        className="link">Original post</a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If the children need to pass data to parents, a rule of thumb is that the state should belong in the parent, not the child.

Comment: Which props are you trying to update? I see that you have `content` which an array of images. Do you intend to save the vote count on each image? Or do you intend to save the vote count in the Options component?

Comment: I'm trying to save vote count for each image. On my App component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by consolidating your state into the App component. Save the votes on your content array on each picture object. Pass the upvote and downvote functions down to each children and call them from your button clicks. I would also calculate the styling based on the props, rather than use state.

App

```
function App() {
  let initialstate = images.map(image => {
    image.votes = 0;
    return image;
  });

  const [content, setContent] = useState(initialstate);

  const upVote = index => {
    setContent(content[index].votes + 1);
  };

  const downVote = index => {
    setContent(content[index].votes - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="grid">
        {content.map((picture, index) => {
          return <Card key={index} picture={picture} index={index} upVote={upVote} downVote={downVote} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Card

```
function Card({ index, picture, ...props }) {
  const upVote = () => props.upVote(index);
  const downVote = () => props.downVote(index);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="container">
        <img
          width="300"
          alt={`id: ${picture.id}`}
          src={picture.src}
          className="image"
        />
        <Options votes={picture.votes} originalPost={picture.original_post} upVote={upVote} downVote={downVote}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Options

```
function Options({ votes, originalPost, upVote, downVote }) {
  let styling = '#696969';

  if (count > 0) {
    styling = '#008000';
  } else if (count < 0) {
    styling = '#B22222';
  } else {
    styling = '#696969';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button title="Down vote" onClick={downVote} className="buttons">
        -
      </button>

      <span title="Vote counter" style={{ color: styling }} className="counter">
        {votes}
      </span>

      <button title="Up vote" onClick={upVote} className="buttons">
        +
      </button>
      <br></br>

      <a
        href={originalPost}
        target="_blank"
        title="Click to check the original post"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        className="link"
      >
        Original post
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I got an error about the index on the up/down vote functions 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'votes' of undefined'. Just to clarify me, the index is the same i pass as props to key on the card component?

Comment: How have you defined the `images` variable? You will need to add the votes properties to each element in the images array. 

`const images = [{ id: 1, src: '', original_post: '', votes: 0 }];`

Comment: > Just to clarify me, the index is the same i pass as props to key on the card component?

yes, the key prop contains the index, and so I pass the index back to the parent function by using the key prop.

Comment: @lucazpinheiro I updated App to initialize the images with a vote count of 0.

Comment: I got the same error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'votes' of undefined

Comment: @lucazpinheiro ah yes, I see the mistake. I forgot that you can't access the key prop inside a component. It's a special React internal prop. Anyways, I updated the Card component to take in an index prop, and that gets passed to upVote and downVote. Can you try it now?

Comment: @lucazpinheiro glad to help!

Comment: Oh, i forgot, sorry